# Bootstrap button padding not loading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, padding

I'm trying to get some buttons to work in Bootstrap 5:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <a class="btn-primary">0000</a>
      <button class="btn-primary">0000</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the styles aren't being applied correctly, the buttons appear to be missing the rounded corners and the padding:

[image]

I'm only loading the styles from `<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` which I'm pretty sure is what I always do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to `btn` align with other custom bootstrap classes. Read about [buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/) here

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <a class="btn btn-primary">0000</a>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">0000</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change class class="btn-primary" to class="btn btn-primary"

Answer (score 0):

It misses the "btn" class.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">asdasda</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the `btn` class

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button">0000</a>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">0000</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/buttons/
>
> Bootstrap includes several predefined button styles, each serving its own semantic purpose, with a few extras thrown in for more control.
>
> **Button tags**
>
> The `.btn` classes are designed to be used with the `<button>` element. However, you can also use these classes on `<a>` or `<input>` elements (though some browsers may apply a slightly different rendering).
>
> When using button classes on `<a>` elements that are used to trigger in-page functionality (like collapsing content), rather than linking to new pages or sections within the current page, these links should be given a `role="button`" to appropriately convey their purpose to assistive technologies such as screen readers.